# MS Access Error 3211 When deleting a temp table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a function that is creating a temp table (using `SELECT INTO`) to cache some calculations. Based on information I found I'm first checking to see if the temp table exists and removing it if so, then generating the temp table.

The process seemed to work correctly but now I'm running into an issue where the code that checks for the table and deletes it is getting a 3211 Error - "The database engine is could not lock table..." when the table already exists.

I'm not sure if it's something I'm doing when creating the temp table or at some point later that is causing it to be locked and unable to be removed. The temp table is used to populate a report.

Here is the function that is throwing the error:

```
Sub CacheRewardsReportData(ReviewYearID As Integer)
    On Error GoTo Err_Proc

    Dim strSQL As String

    If TableExists(strTable) Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strTable
    End If

    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [tblTempRewardsReport] FROM [qryReportRewards_Cache] WHERE [ReviewYearID] = " & ReviewYearID & ";"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Err_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Err_Proc:
    Misc.LogError Err.Number, Err.Description, "CacheRewardsReportData"
    Resume Err_Exit
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably already tried this, but Compact and Repair might help.

Comment: @HansUp I don't believe the report is open. Is there a way to check?

I'll try the delete and see if that works.

Comment: @HansUp Switching to deleting all the rows and using an append query seems to fixed the issue. Thanks! If you would like to enter it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access didn't let me delete the table itself, but did allow me to delete all the rows from the table and then load it with fresh data.

So I changed the function to the following, which corrected the issue.

```
Sub CacheRewardsReportData(ReviewYearID as Integer)
    On Error GoTo Err_Proc

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblTempRewardsReport;"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTempRewardsReport SELECT * FROM [qryReportRewards_Cache] WHERE [ReviewYearID] = " & ReviewYearID & ";"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Err_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Err_Proc:
    Misc.LogError Err.Number, Err.Description, "CacheRewardsReportData"
    Resume Err_Exit
End Sub
```

Thanks again for the help!